# How to access sibling elements in a site while scraping using python and Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the "listing-key-specs" of this site:

https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?radius=30&postcode=ss156ee&onesearchad=Used&make=Renault&model=zoe&page=1

But I am only interested in the miles spec and not bhp or any other spec.

if I type

```
specs=article.find('ul',class_="listing-key-specs")
print(specs.text)
```

I might get 6 pieces of information:

```
2015 (65 reg)
Hatchback
13,033 miles
88bhp
Automatic
Electric**
```

If I type

```
print(specs.li.text)
```

I will only get the first spec i.e

**2015 (65 reg)**

How can I select a particular piece of spec? let's say the 'miles' spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or simply:

```
print(specs('li')[2].text)
```

Output:

```
15,285 miles
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize it could be accessed like a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the first child li

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
res= requests.get('https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?radius=30&postcode=ss156ee&onesearchad=Used&make=Renault&model=zoe&page=1')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
details = [item.text for item in soup.select('.listing-key-specs li:first-child')]
print(details)
```

Less efficient is

```
.listing-key-specs li:nth-of-type(1)
```

or

```
.listing-key-specs :nth-child(1)
```

or

```
.listing-key-specs li:first-of-type
```

- I am using latest BeautifulSoup 4.7.1